# How to recreate Windows 10 Startup folder

Tags: windows-10, boot

A little while back I accidently deleted my startup folder, and I tested this by opening the "Run" application and executing `shell:startup`. Doing so returned an error saying that the startup folder did not exist. Does anyone know how to recreate the Startup folder for a particular user?

Answer (score 1):

Try recreating the startup folder, as the default location of the Windows User Startup folder is:

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
```

A useful tool to examine the special Windows folders and their locations is Nirsoft's [SpecialFoldersView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/special_folders_view.html). For example, it displays the Windows Environment Variable for that folder:

```
%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
```

[image: User Startup Folder]